# How do I reset a doctrine entity in my preUpdate method?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to figure out how to rollback the state of a changed entity while in the `preUpdate` method (I'm using the annotation method if that makes a difference).

I've tried using the `EntityManager::refresh($entity)` and while it does seem to revert the entity, it still goes ahead and saves the changes to the database.

I've read that I need to recalculate the change set by calling `$em->getUnitOfWork()->computeChangeSet($em->getClassMetaData(get_class($this)), $this);` however this doesn't do the trick.

Is there anyway to get the `UnitOfWork` to ignore the changes/re-calculate properly?

```
<?php 
class Status extends Entity {

    /**
     * @PreUpdate
     */
    public function preUpdate() {
        if (!$this->canSave()) {
            $this->reset();
        }
    }

    public function reset() {
        $em = self::getEntityManager();
        $em->refresh($this);
        $em->getUnitOfWork()
           ->computeChangeSet($em->getClassMetaData(get_class($this)), $this);
    }

    public function canSave() { return false; }
?>

<?php
// Bootstrap for testing/debugging
include 'common.php';

$log = \Zend_Registry::get('log');

$x = Status::find(31); // Retrieve entity from DB
$log->debug("Original: " . $x->getDateLastSeen() . "\n");

$x->setDateLastSeen(new \DateTime());
$log->debug("Set to: " . $x->getDateLastSeen() . "\n");

$x->save();
$log->debug("Saved to: " . $x->getDateLastSeen() . "\n");
```

Outputs:

```
2013-02-14T23:13:22+00:00 DEBUG (7): Original: 2013-02-14 23:08:22
2013-02-14T23:13:22+00:00 DEBUG (7): Set to: 2013-02-14 23:13:22
2013-02-14T23:13:22+00:00 DEBUG (7): Saved to: 2013-02-14 23:08:22
```

Everything *looks okay*, however when I look at my database log I see:

```
409705 Query    UPDATE devices_statuses SET date_last_seen = '2013-02-14 23:13:22' WHERE id = 31
409705 Query    commit
```

Answer (score 2):

This is already handled by the ORM itself (see https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.3.2/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php#L970-L974 )

The problem here is that the `DateTime` instance assigned to `date_last_seen` (or better the field mapped to it) has a different object hash (check it with [`spl_object_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-object-hash.php)).

For the ORM, this is a changeset. To effectively reset your instance, you will need to manually call [`Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork#clearEntityChangeSet(spl_object_hash($this))`](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.3.2/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php#L2889-L2898).

Also, consider moving this code out of the entity into a dedicated event listener: your entity should not be aware of the `EntityManager` or about the persistence layer in any way.

Comment: I traced through the `recomputeSingleEntityChangeSet` however I think that the issue is that [`$orgValue !== $actualValue`](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.3.2/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php#L876-880) is false so the changeset never gets populated and the [`array_merge`](https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/2.3.2/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php#L883-889) never gets called to *reset* the values.

Comment: Hmm... You're right. You will need to manually clear the changeset as stated above anyway.

Comment: Thanks for validating. I also found that I *should be using `preFlush`*, which is called prior to the calculating the changeset. More efficient and bypasses the issue afaik.

Comment: @hafichuk if this works for you don't forget to validate the answer. Good hint on `preFlush`!